# Is there a way to check for new objects/entries in a Django database?

Tags: python, database, django, django-models, reload

I am writing a Python server in Tornado which works with HTML5 WebSockets. My server works by creating a connection with the client browser through JavaScript. Once a connection is created, it stays open until the browser (or the server closes it). I need to periodically check if one of my models has changed or if the database has updated.

Here's code example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
>>> mymodels = MyModel.objects.all()
>>> len(mymodels)
150
>>> # Some stuff happens on the client and the model is changed, one more entry is added
>>> mymodels = MyModel.objects.all()
>>> len(mymodels)
151
```

This all happens within a server application where the changes to the model will occur within one "session" of the server script running. Is there anyway I can check for new objects or refresh my Django database?

An example of what I mean if it still isn't clear: Let's say I have a model called MyModel. When the server script is first run, it has 150 different entries or database rows. I establish a WebSocket connection with my server from my client and request that I be updated whenever a new change occurs. Somewhere else in my client, some other user does something that creates a new row in my database for the MyModel class. My server, while still keeping the same connection that it has to the original client already, needs to be able to detect that change without stopping its execution.

Checking periodically isn't the problem, its actually making sure that the Django database API is aware of the newly added information. Is there anyway I can ensure that that happens? **The originally posted example code does not actually work.** The length of MyModel.objects.all() is still 150 no matter how many items I add to the model. If I restart my Django shell, it updates the count.

Some other things I have tried:

- Reloading the models module using the built-in reload() function.
- Filtering the model for a certain set of MyModel
- Using raw SQL queries to both select everything and filter based on certain conditions

All of these methods keep returning the same number of MyModel objects no matter how many changes I make to the database. Interestingly enough, running the raw SQL in MySQL Workbench produces the expected results.

Comment: you can make an ajax request at specified time intervals, and check for change in count, and refresh if count is not the same

Comment: Django doesn't have a "database", its model calls are just wrappers around SQL calls to the database.  There are 2 ways your database server can tell you if something changed: you polling the database for changes, (which consumes a lot of time and resources) -- or use some database queuing mechanism, (which are usually in Java, but can be attached to python processes).

Comment: Is your script multi-threaded? Have you considered implementing a pre or post-save hook?

Comment: What's your server script CONCRETELY doing?

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity, I've updated my post. Thank you for your help. The problem isn't with long-polling or using AJAX. It's just about checking for updates in the database within the same execution of a long-running script.

Comment: If you're in the middle of a transaction, you need to commit it BEFORE re-counting. Also, if you were using the same queryset the query result would be cached as well but it seems that you're creating a new one.

Comment: I guess I should clarify again: I am not committing or adding anything in the server script at all. That all happens elsewhere in the application. My server script just happens to be running. I'm wondering why Django isn't updating the count based on those changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FIGURED IT OUT!
The simplest way to force Django to update its database reference is to close the database connection. Django will automatically create a new one as it needs to.

> django.db.close_connection()

If you have changes that need to be committed before you close the connection, this will accomplish the same as above, but keep the changes that you have made. (i.e. you will not need to close the connection as this refreshes the database anyway)

> django.db.connection._commit()

Thanks for your comments and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If it's all within one "session" of the server-side script running, maybe you've got the whole thing running in one DB transaction (which would mean that nothing else could see it) - although the fact that you can see them incrementally in Workbench suggests not. Having said that, it's worth checking out what you're doing with transactions.

Also, have you read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets) to make sure that Django is doing what you think it's doing?